# Keras jupyter notebook outputs blocks during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

When using Keras in a Jupyter Notebook environment, during training my Notebook crashes. While running the fit function, apart from the normal training progress, a lot of squares appear. In fact, there are so many squares the browser crashes...

When running the same code in a normal terminal these squares do not appear.

Here is an example of the output:

```
Train on 33164 samples, validate on 8292 samples
Epoch 1/3
  960/33164 [..............................] - ETA: 46s - loss: 0.1997 - acc: 0.9394
```

Hope anybody can help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

see this [issue on github](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4676)

in short 4 options :

- Use command lines instead of ipython notebooks
- Use `verbose=0` or `verbose=2` in `fit()`, the first will not output anything, the second will only output one log line per epoch.
- If you use tensorflow as backend you can monitor everything on tensorboard (slow but better than nothing)
- You can use the [RemoteMonitor callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#remotemonitor) but this seems to require a bit of work.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for finding the issue on Github, I think you are indeed correct that wanting to view progress live in my notebook is a bit too much. Will use verbose=2 next time.

Comment: verbose=2 is great, the only thing missing is eta for the current epoch.